# Wordpress 5.7, Theme 2021. How to change the main menu submenu items to white

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Wordpress 5.7, Theme 2021.

1 How do you change the colour of the submenu items in the Main Menu?
I'm a Wordpress newbie, basic/intermediate knowledge of CSS.

2 How do I change the background colour of the main menu and submenu?

This additional CSS makes the main menu items white. I want to do the same to the submenus.

```
*start of menu */
/*menu background */
.menu-wrapper {
background: rgba(204,153,51,.75);
}

a#primary-menu-list {
color:white;
}

.primary-navigation .primary-menu-container > ul > .menu-item > a
{color:white;}

.svg-icon
{color:white;}

/*end of menu */
```

Answer (score 0):

As this theme supports CSS variables right now - I'd suggest you not override selectors, but override just variables. You need to add to your CSS these lines, replace with the colors you really want to use and make sure they override default styles

```
:root {
    --primary-nav--color-link:  #ffffff;
    --primary-nav--color-link-hover: #cecece;
    --primary-nav--color-text: #000000;
}
```

Here's the list of available variables for the main navigation

```
--primary-nav--font-family: var(--global--font-secondary);
--primary-nav--font-family-mobile: var(--global--font-primary);
--primary-nav--font-size: var(--global--font-size-md);
--primary-nav--font-size-sub-menu: var(--global--font-size-xs);
--primary-nav--font-size-mobile: var(--global--font-size-sm);
--primary-nav--font-size-sub-menu-mobile: var(--global--font-size-sm);
--primary-nav--font-size-button: var(--global--font-size-xs);
--primary-nav--font-style: normal;
--primary-nav--font-style-sub-menu-mobile: normal;
--primary-nav--font-weight: normal;
--primary-nav--font-weight-button: 500;
--primary-nav--color-link: var(--global--color-primary);
--primary-nav--color-link-hover: var(--global--color-primary-hover);
--primary-nav--color-text: var(--global--color-primary);
--primary-nav--padding: calc(0.66 * var(--global--spacing-unit));
--primary-nav--border-color: var(--global--color-primary);
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and quick response. I'd forgotten about the CSS variables.  I still cannot get the submenu which are triggered to open by Javascript to use the same colours.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to style
`.primary-navigation .sub-menu .menu-item>a {
color: var(--primary-nav--color-link)
}`
If this will not help - at least post your generated HTML layout

Comment: I followed your ideas and got it to work.  I forgot to mention the background color requirement. The 2 screenshots show the remaining issue with White text on Whitish background, when I click on the submenu heading (rather than the + key)

Answer (score 0):

Attempt 1:
I failed with the CSS, but then looked carefully in:

Plugin: Options for Twenty Twenty-One (free version)
Customising Nav Options

### set  Nav Background Color:   selected the relevant color

Attempt 2:
Without the plugin

This works well when I use the + key to trigger the drop down
If I click on the submenu heading the heading is hard to read (white text on whitish background).
[image: Works well with + key to open menu]

[image: Clicking on menu heading gives white text on whitish background, hard to read]

Additional CSS

```
:root {
/*submenu color */
    --primary-nav--color-link:  white;
/*main menu color */
    --primary-nav--color-link-hover: white;
    
/* where does this take effect?
--primary-nav--color-text: red;
*/
  --primary-nav--color-text: #000000;
      
        
}
/*this is the background of the main menu only, not submenu */
.menu-wrapper {
background: rgba(204,153,51,.75);
}


/*
 this is for the submenu (drop down menus)
*/

.primary-navigation .sub-menu .menu-item>a { color: var(--primary-nav--color-link); 
background:rgba(204,153,51,.75); */


}

.svg-icon
{color:white;}
```